# How do I conclude that $G(a)= a_1^\frac{1}{n},...,a_n^\frac{1}{n}$ must obtain its maximum when $a_1=...=a_n = U(a)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

In the **AM-GM Inequality**, how do I conclude that $G(a)= a_1^\frac{1}{n},...,a_n^\frac{1}{n}$ must obtain its maximum when $a_1=...=a_n = U(a)$ and ($U(a)= \frac{a_1+...a_n}{n}$ is the arithmetic mean)? Since if the $a_i$'s are not equal, then $G$ can be increased by the following procedure described below:

If the $a_i$'s are not all equal, then $G(a)$ can be increase in such a way that $U(a)$ remains unaltered. To do this, we suppose that $a_1$ = min $a_i <$ max ${a_i}=a_2$. Then we replace both $a_1$ and $a_2$ with the $\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method you increase $G$ by altering $a_1$ and $a_2$ and replacing both with $\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$. In every iteration of this method you are in fact *making* the $a_i$ equal. This does seem to support the idea that $a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots{a_n}$ is maximised at $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n$. This should answer your doubts.

But this isn't a proof.

There are many proofs of the $A.M-G.M$ inequality. Here is one.

Consider the function $f(x)=\log(x)$. This is a concave function, so we have,

$$\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\cdots+f(x_n)}{n} \leqslant f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)$$

Using the properties of logarithm, we obtain,

$$\log(\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots{x_n}})\le \log\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)$$

Because $f$ is increasing, this is equivalent to the $AM-GM$ inequality.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is true is to use Lagrange Multiplier method. So assume that a(1) + a(2) +...+ a(n) = C - C is a constant > 0. Then consider the function G(a(1),..,a(n)) = a(1)a(2)..a(n)  ( just the product of all the a(i)'s ). Let F(a(1),..,a(n)) = a(1) + a(2) +...+ a(n) - C. Then grad(G) = t*grad(F) <==> (a(2)a(3)..a(n), a(1)a(3)...a(n),...,a(1)a(2)..a(n-1)) = (t,t,t...,t). This means:

a(2)a(3)a(4)...a(n) = t

a(1)a(3)a(4)...a(n) = t

a(1)a(2)a(4)...a(n) = t
.....................

a(1)a(2).......a(n-1) = t.

Solve this system of equations we have:  a(1) = a(2) = ...= a(n).

And thus the maximum of G occurs when a(1) = a(2) =... = a(n).

Comment: Could you please edit your argument in LaTex form? I am having a hard time reading it.